# Ошибка C4700 VS 2019

Tags: c++

Ошибка Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C4700    uninitialized local variable 'tmp_double_vector' used  isdt    Isodata.cpp 186

Мой код

``````
k << 1;
        pdn = k * (k - 1) / 2;
        if ((cl_m == malloc(k * sizeof(int))) == NULL)
            error("bad memory allocation");
        if ((cl_d == malloc(k * sizeof(double))) == NULL)
            error("bad memory allocation");
        if ((cl_pd == malloc(pdn * sizeof(double))) == NULL)
            error("bad memory allocation");
        if ((cl_pi == malloc(pdn * sizeof(int))) == NULL)
            error("bad memory allocation");
        if ((cl_pj == malloc(pdn * sizeof(int))) == NULL)
            error("bad memory allocation");
        if ((cl_ms == malloc(k * sizeof(double))) == NULL)
            error("bad memory allocation");
        if ((cl_msc == malloc(k * sizeof(int))) == NULL)
            error("bad memory allocation");
        if ((cl_s == malloc(k * sizeof(double*))) == NULL)
            error("bad memory allocation");
        for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
            if ((cl_s[i] == malloc(m * sizeof(double))) == NULL)
                error("bad memory allocation");
        if ((tmp_double_vector == malloc(k * sizeof(double))) == NULL)
            error("bad memory allocation");
        if ((tmp_int_vector == malloc(k * sizeof(int))) == NULL)
            error("bad memory allocation");
        k >> 1;
`````
``````

Answer (score 0):

Вы везде вместо присвоения написали проверку на равенство...

Как я понимаю, вы хотели получить

```
if ((cl_s = malloc(k * sizeof(double*))) == NULL)

...

if ((tmp_double_vector = malloc(k * sizeof(double))) == NULL)
```

Забавно, что обычно делают наоборот - вместо проверки пишут один символ `=`, получая присвоение...

Comment: Теперь у меня другая ошибка `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active) E0513 a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "double *" isdt 169 `

Comment: Ну что, вам все разжевывать? выполните приведение `(double*)malloc...`. Не будьте таким беспомощным, старайтесь думать самостоятельно, в чем проблема. Тем более что компилятор обычно достаточно понятно пишет...